# Building insulated room for server racks in a storage unit

Tags: insulation, storage

For this question I am not necessarily looking for complete answers. What I am hoping for is a place I can find complete information (a book, youtube videos, etc).

I am renting a storage unit, and I want to build a small "room," perhaps mounted on a pallet so that it can be semi-portable. I want it to be insulated and built with air conditioning and filtration, because I want to house computer servers in it.

It can be assumed this room would be mostly safe from weather since it'd be inside a storage unit. But moisture is a big concern since the unit is essentially just an unfinished garage.

On a high level I can envision how to do this, but I have never actually built anything like that and it is not something I want to just guess at.

More broadly then, what are good resources for learning how to built well-insulated, (relatively) air tight storage boxes?

I have tried Googling various combinations of keywords but most of the results I get are about thing such as finishing a basement, which is not really close enough to what (I think) since I want to build a free-standing room.

Comment: I would say — start with a resource on how to build a refrigerator. That’s basically what you are building.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but this reminds me of fermentation chambers that homebrewers build; they have similar requirements for insulation and conditioning the space against contaminants and condensation. You might find some useful resources looking at those builds and instructions.

Comment: Have you looked for server enclosures? Usually available from a simple cupboard to a fully environmental controlled solution with a price top match. Or are you expecting a cheap solution. And there are lots of results for "server enclosures", none of which included "basement" in the ones i found...

Comment: Your question is too broad for this site. You're going to need to decide on a rough strategy (lumber framing, steel framing, fiberglass insulation, foam insulation, etc.), and then come back and ask more specific questions about the problems you encounter. Simply put, you won't find a manual for something so vague.

Comment: Are you going to be able to get fresh air in and send hot/humid air out? (Big holes in the wall, or a window that you can open and mount an air conditioner in.) Alternatively, can you run a set of refrigerant lines through the wall and mount a compressor outside? Because without one of those options you will quickly pump heat from the conditioned section to the unconditioned section and overwhelm the unconditioned area to the degree that the system will fail.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact The unconditioned side would be considerably larger than the conditioned side (maybe ten times larger), and is essentially just a sheet-metal garage. Would that still be a problem?

Comment: Yes, it would still be a problem. Essentially your computers are heaters. Your air conditioner is a heater (because it uses electricity which becomes heat) and it pumps the computer heat to the other room. Put another way: If the computers running by themselves in the sheet-metal garage would get way too hot over time then putting them inside another box isn't going to make any long-term difference. In fact, when we run air conditioning in a house we are heating the rest of the earth - just to a level that is essentially irrelevant. But contained inside the garage it is very relevant.

Comment: VtC because it's way too vague.  Kudos to @ecnerwal for a constructive answer but why do you need a storage facility for your servers?  Why can't they be in your home?  There are good reasons, but they lead to more questions ... why are you choosing an unconditioned facility to start with?  How much power will you be consuming and how much heat producing?  Why don't you just rent a cabinet in a public data center?  Why, for that matter, don't you use public cloud for whatever you're doing?  There are good reasons that produce more questions.  What does "portable" mean?  Forklift and flatbed?

Comment: This is unrealistic. You'll have trouble finding a storage unit that will furnish free "conditioned" electricity, reliable internet access, appropriate air conditioning, etc. And it's likely if they found out what you were doing, they'd put the kibosh on it. You'd be better off renting a piece of AWS/Google Cloud, or similar from a professional provider. It would likely be cheaper than a storage unit anyhow. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stressed skin panels that are used to build walk-in coolers (commercial scale refrigerators & freezers) would be the most straightforward way to do this, other than getting an entire refrigerated truck body or refrigerated shipping container (used, presumably.) Those are metal skins (sometime fiberglass for the truck bodies) over foam. Stressed skin panels for houses are typically plywood or OSB over foam, and could also work.

*Most* storage units would lack the available power and network to run the whole business. The "truck body" or "refrigerated shipping container" options remove the need to put it out of the weather, so you'd just need a place to park it with power and network available.

Moisture is unlikely to be a problem, since you're running a lot of electric heaters (which you think of as servers) in a box, so it will range from warm and dry to hot and dry, or you'll be actively cooling it to prevent overheating which will drive it back towards warm and dry (it's inefficient to aim for cool and dry, servers don't really need it to be all that cool, so unless cooling is free (winter) it does not pay to do that.)

Comment: Got some useful research starting points from the comments and both answers but I'll mark this one as the answer since it has the most info. Thank you!

Comment: "a lot of electric heaters (which you think of as servers)" So. Very. True! I had an extra AC vent installed in my office to provide cool air for _one_, low-power server because of the vast amount of heat it was pumping out.

Answer (score 1):

Would think shipping container conversion would be similar. Try there. "Ambition Strikes" a home stead couple, did this to house solar batteries/inverter/charge controller, etc. May give some ideas

Comment: Will check this out. Thanks!